# Find dups in excel column using vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, duplicates

I am having a problem with finding duplicates in an excel column that is created via VBscript.

I currently am grabbing data from a DB opening an excel file, placing the data within and then sorting the data alphabetically ascending on **column E** (if this isn't needed it can easily be removed).

Now the problem that I am faced with is that I am trying to find any duplicates within that **column E** (Errors).

If there is a duplicate I would like to copy the duplicate and paste it into another sheet **(column A)** that I have created

```
Set oWS7 = oWB.Worksheets(7)
oWB.Sheets(7).Name = "Dups"
```

And in **column B** of oWS7 I would like to put all the corresponding **column C's** (accounts) from the original worksheet.

So that there would be a **1 Error** to many account's ratio. If there are no duplicates I would like to have them left alone.  I'm not sure how clear this is but any questions/help on this would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean VBScript or VBA?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make the following assumptions:

- The content in the worksheet starts in the first row
- The first row (and only the first row) is a header row.
- There are no empty rows between header row and data rows.
- The data is already sorted.

If these assumptions apply the following should work (once you put in the correct sheet number):

```
Set data = oWB.Sheets(...)  '<-- insert correct sheet number here

j = 1
For i = 3 To data.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  If data.Cells(i, 5).Value = data.Cells(i-1, 5).Value Then
    oWS7.Cells(j, 1).Value = data.Cells(i, 5).Value
    oWS7.Cells(j, 2).Value = data.Cells(i, 3).Value
    j = j + 1
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

'**How To find Repeted Cell values from source excel sheet**.

```
Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.application")
oXL.Visible = True
Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("ExcelFilePath")
Set oSheet = oWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")         'Source Sheet in workbook

r = oSheet.usedrange.rows.Count
c = oSheet.usedrange.columns.Count

inttotal = 0
For i = 1 To r
    For j = 1 To c
        If oSheet.Cells(i,j).Value = "aaaa" Then
            inttotal = inttotal+1
        End If
    Next
Next

MsgBox inttotal

oWB.Close
oXL.Quit
```